# $n^{n-1}-1$ is a multiple of $k$

Tags: number-theory

> Find the number of integers $k$ with $2 \leq k \leq 1000$ satisfying the following property:
>
> - For every positive integer $n$ relatively prime to $k$, $n^{n-1}-1$ is a multiple of $k$.

Let $k = 2^{\alpha_1}3^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}$ be the prime decomposition of $k$. Then by the Chinese Remainder Theorem $n^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{k}$ for all $n$ such that $\gcd(n,k) = 1$ if and only if\begin{align*}n^{n-1} &\equiv 1 \pmod{2^{\alpha_1}}\\n^{n-1} &\equiv 1 \pmod{3^{\alpha_2}}\\&\vdots\\n^{n-1} &\equiv 1 \pmod{p_n^{\alpha_n}}\end{align*} for all $n$ such that $\gcd(n,k) = 1$. How can we continue?

Comment: $k$ is even (otherwise take $n=2$). If $k$ is co-prime to 3, then $k$ must divide $8$ and each of $k=2,4,8$ do satisfy the property. Similarly, ask yourself whether $k$ is co-prime to 5,7,11 etc.

Comment: @Aravind Why if $k$ is coprime to $3$ then $k \mid 8$?

Comment: Just check your definition.  If $k>3$ and satisfies the property, and $k$ is co-prime to 3, take $n=3$.

Comment: @Aravind I don't see how to continue from this to solve the question.

Comment: "for **every** positive integer $n$ relatively prime to $k$" => $n=2$ is prime to all odd numbers => $n^{n-1}-1=1$ is not a multiple of any $2 \leq k$ => no $k$ (?)

Comment: Yeah, just realized the case  $n=2$ means no such odd $k$ exists.

Comment: @GCab Or $2$ is not relatively prime to $k$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: yes,sorry, I forgot to add *odd*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\gcd(n,k)=1$ then $\gcd(n+k,k)=1$. So:

$$1\equiv (n+k)^{n+k-1}\equiv n^{n+k-1}=n^{n-1}n^k\pmod{k}$$

and hence $n^k\equiv 1\pmod{k}$ for all $n$ relatively prime to $k$.

Now if $0<n<k$ with $\gcd(n,k)=1$, then:

$$1\equiv (k-n)^{k-n-1} \equiv (-1)^{k-n-1} n^kn^{-(n-1)}n^{-2}\pmod{k}$$

But $n^k\equiv n^{-(n-1)}\equiv 1\pmod{k}$ so you have $$n^2\equiv (-1)^{k-n-1}\pmod{k}$$

That should reduce the problem greatly for case-by-case analysis. The only prime powers where every relatively prime square is $\pm 1$ are $2,4,8,3,5$. And $k$ has to be a product of these.

We know $k$ must be even, since otherwise $(2,k)=1$ and $k$ must divide $2^{2-1}-1=1$, we are most of the way.

When $k$ is even, we get that $n$ is odd, and hence $(-1)^{k-n-1}=1$ so we need $n^2\equiv 1\pmod{k}$ for all relevant $n$. But that means that $5$ can't be a factor.

This leaves us with $k=2,4,8,6,12,24$. We can quickly check each case.

---

Okay, more verbosely, you need to prove this lemma:

> If $p^{a}\mid k$ and there is some $n_0$ such that $\gcd(n_0,p^a)=1$ and $n_0^2\not\equiv 1\pmod{p^a}$, then there is an $n$ with $\gcd(n,k)\neq 1$ such that $n^{2}\not\equiv 1\pmod{k}$.

Essentially, this is because you can write $k=p^bk'$ for $\gcd(k',p)=1$ and then solve the Chinese remainder question:

$$n\equiv n_0\pmod{p^b}\\
n\equiv 1\pmod{k'}$$

This gives you an $n$ with $n^2\not\equiv -1\pmod{p^b}$ so $n^2\not\equiv -1\pmod{k}$.

Comment: Because, modulo $p$, there are at least $(p-1)/2$ distinct squares, so if $p>5$ there are at least three distinct squares modulo $p$. If $p\mid k$ then there are at least three distinct squares modulo $k$. Then we just check - $3^2\equiv 9\not\equiv \pm 1\pmod{16}$, $2^2\equiv 4\not\equiv\pm 1\pmod{9}$, and $2^2\not\equiv\pm 1\pmod{25}$.

Comment: So the answer is $6$?

Comment: I haven't actually checked those values $k$. I think it works for all of them, but not 100% sure.

Comment: Why can't $5$ be a factor?

Comment: Because I showed later that $n^2\equiv 1$ when $k$ is even, and $-1$ is a square modulo $5$.

Comment: Yes, but $-1$ is a square when $n = 2$, which is not relatively prime to $k$.

Comment: @user19405892 Added explicit lemma at the end to explain why we can rule out factors.